# Unexpected behavior when routing to children with componentless route in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-router, angular-route-guards, angular-routerlink

I have an question about Angular 5 routing.

If I declare routes like this below, the `route guard` is called every time I route to one of the components via `routerLink` in html.

```
const routes: Route[] = [ 
  { path: 'comp1', component: Comp1Component, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'comp2', component: Comp2Component, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
]
```

But if I declare it with a `componentless` route, the guard is only called when the app starts. And when I switch routes in html the guard is never called again.

```
const routes: Route[] = [
  { path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
  { path: 'comp1', component: Comp1Component},
  { path: 'comp2', component: Comp2Component}
]}
```

Why is the route guard in my scenario with componentless parent route not called every time a route to a component?

Comment: does not it makes sense ? You've added Route Guard for Parent Route. Once Parent is activated, now you're in child route. So why `AuthGuard` will be invoked ?

Comment: That makes sense. But if I route back to the parent route the `AuthGuard` is also not called again. Why is that? Is it because there is no other route at the same level as the parent route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess your guard must implement the `CanActivateChild` interface.

https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateChild

```
const routes: Route[] = [
    { path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard], canActivateChild: [AuthGuard], children: [
        { path: 'comp1', component: Comp1Component},
        { path: 'comp2', component: Comp2Component}
    ]}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should work.

Let's say you have an admin section that you want to guard:

```
{
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [..]
}
```

Once you try to go to `/admin` your guard will be called. Once you are in the admin section the children will not trigger this guard.

If you want to protect the child routes, then yo uneed to use `CanActivateChild`

```
const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            { path: 'comp1', component: Comp1Component},
            { path: 'comp2', component: Comp2Component}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

The AuthGuard should implement both [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) and [CanActivateChild](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateChild)

You can find more information in the docs: [Route guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards)